# Iterated wreath product

Tags: group-theory

Can someone tell me what is **iterated wreath product** or where I can appropriate definition? I'm trying to understand one paper and author claims that some elements

> $g_1,...,g_k$ are each of order $n$ and collectively generat the iterated wreath product $(...(G_1 \wr G_{k-1} ) \wr ... \wr G_2 ) \wr G_1 $ where $G_i =\langle g_i \rangle$

Then comes the proof of this fact.

Comment: Do you know what an ordinary, uniterated wreath product is? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wreath_product Assuming so, then simply use parentheses.

Comment: There is a bug in the terminology, due to the fact that in the past "group" meant what's now known as "permutation group", that is "subgroup of the group of permutations of a certain set" and now just means "group" as we all learn, and has a canonical meaning by letting the group left-act on itself. The traditional notion of wreath product was for permutation groups, and can be iterated (and it's associative). This is what's explained in Quang Hoang's answer.

Comment: ... Now the wreath product $H\wr G$ rather means the wreath product for the left actions, and this is not associative (if $C$ is any nontrivial finite group, then $(C\wr C)\wr C$ and $C\wr (C\wr C)$ don't even have the same order). This is rather confusing!

Answer (score 2):

Let $H\le \Sigma_m$ and $G\le \Sigma_n$ be subgroups of the corresponding symmetric groups.

Let $\Sigma_m^k$ be the subgroup of $\Sigma_{mn}$ that permutes $\{(k-1)m+1,\cdots,km\}$. We let $\Sigma_n$ act by permuting the copies $\Sigma^k_m$. 
Then the wreath product
$$H\wr G\cong (H^1\times H^2\times\cdots \times H^n)\rtimes G$$ 
can be defined as the subgroup of the group $$\Sigma_m^1\times \Sigma_m^2\times\cdots\times\Sigma^n_m\le\Sigma_{mn},$$
where $H^k\subset \Sigma^k_m$ is the copy of $H$ given by $H\le\Sigma_m\cong \Sigma^k_m$.

---

For a group $H$ and $G\subset \Sigma_n$, one defines $H\wr G$ as  $H^n\rtimes G$
where $G$ acts by permuting coordinates. This definition agrees with the above when we view $H\subset \Sigma_{H}$.

However, it is most common that one sees iterated wreath product in the study of Sylow subgroups of the symmetric groups, hence the first definition.

---

For references, you can find more detail (and more precise) definition in  Group Theory by Suzuki.